# Why PHP returns 52nd week for 2017-01-01

Tags: php, datetime

Why does [following code](https://3v4l.org/bBQll) return `2017-52` instead of expected `2017-01`?

```
date('Y-W', strtotime('2017-01-01')); // returns "2017-52"
```

Edit:
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809736/php-get-correct-date-by-week-one-of-the-year-using-strtotime), there are rules applicable to the first week of the year. Unfortunatelly, this behaviour may cause date FROM to become greater than date TO. To fix this I use following code to calculate the week:

```
function getWeek($timestamp)
{
    $ts1 = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,date('Y', $timestamp));
    $ts2 = mktime(0,0,0,date('n', $timestamp),date('j', $timestamp),date('Y', $timestamp));
    $days = ceil(($ts2 - $ts1) / 86400);
    $week = ceil($days / 7);
    $yearWeek = date('Y', $timestamp).'-'.str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // gives 2017-00 for January 1st
    return $yearWeek;
}
```

Comment: Because January 1 was a Sunday, the prior week (52) is the one returned. From the docs - *Wis theISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php get correct date by week one of the year using strtotime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809736/php-get-correct-date-by-week-one-of-the-year-using-strtotime)

Comment: So to ensure I will get 1st week `00` of the year, I must insert into timestamp  at least 4th day in a week - e.g. `date('Y-W', strtotime('2017-01-05'));` returns correctly `2017-01`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because January 1 was a Sunday, the prior week (52) is the one returned. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - *W is the ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday*

[image]

Comment: Love the screenshot

Comment: Why not 2016 - 52?

Comment: Because the calculation is for 2017 and January 1 is *in* the 52nd week as far as `W` is concerned @Progrock It is one of PHP's less than perfect time calculations, but it does make sense in the grand scheme of things.